# Very confusing R feature - completion of list item names

Tags: r

I found a very suprising and unpleasant feature of R - it completes list item names!!! See the following code:

```
a <- list(cov_spring = "spring")
a$cov <- c()
a$cov
# spring  ## I expect it to be empty!!! I've set it empty!
a$co
# spring
a$c
```

I don't know what to do with that.... I need to be able to set $cov to NULL and have $cov_spring there at the same time!!! And use $cov separately!! This is annoying!

My question:

1. What is going on here? How is this possible, what is the logic behind?
2. Is there some easy fix, how to turn this completion off? I need to use list items cov_spring and cov independently as if they are normal variables. No damn completion please!!!

Comment: If you do `a[["cov_spring"]]` there's no autocompletion.

Comment: thank you @StéphaneLaurent! That's a good solution. Anyway do you know why is this and if this can be turned off? I was used to `$cov` because it's much shorter

Comment: a$cov_spring<-c() results in an empty list

Comment: For assignement there's no autocompletion. See `?Extract`.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent yes, apparently, but for reading the value it is...

Comment: Just curious, how is it that you haven't accepted an answer in almost two years? Are all of the provided answers (not all questions have one) just not good enough?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [`help("$")`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/Extract.html):

```
'x$name' is equivalent to 'x[["name", exact = FALSE]]'
```

When you scroll back and read up on `exact=`:

```
exact: Controls possible partial matching of '[[' when extracting by
      a character vector (for most objects, but see under
      'Environments').  The default is no partial matching.  Value
      'NA' allows partial matching but issues a warning when it
      occurs.  Value 'FALSE' allows partial matching without any
      warning.
```

So this provides you partial matching capability in *both* `$` and `[[` indexing:

```
mtcars$cy
#  [1] 6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 6 8 8 8 8 8 8 4 4 4 4 8 8 8 8 4 4 4 8 6 8 4
mtcars[["cy"]]
# NULL
mtcars[["cy", exact=FALSE]]
#  [1] 6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 6 8 8 8 8 8 8 4 4 4 4 8 8 8 8 4 4 4 8 6 8 4
```

There is no way I can see of to disable the `exact=FALSE` default for `$` (unless you want to mess with `formals`, which I do *not* recommend for the sake of reproducibility and consistent behavior).

Programmatic use of frames and lists (for defensive purposes) should prefer `[[` over `$` for precisely this reason. (It's rare, but I have been bitten by this permissive behavior.)

**Edit**:

For clarity on that last point:

- `mtcars$cyl` becomes `mtcars[["cyl"]]`
- `mtcars$cyl[1:3]` becomes `mtcars[["cyl"]][1:3]`
- `mtcars[,"cy"]` is not a problem, nor is `mtcars[1:3,"cy"]`

Comment: One roundabout solution might be to set `warnPartialMatchDollar` option on and then set R to elevate warnings to errors. Not ideal, though.

Comment: Aaaah, awesome, thanks! Now it's clear... **if there was a solution to change the default for $ to exact = TRUE**, thaat whould be AWESOME!!!!

Comment: (Up front: that option can easily break reproducibility.) Setting `options(warnPartialMatchDollar=FALSE)` has the same caution as setting `options(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`: it works great as long as *your* script (or *your* `~/.Rprofile`) is loaded, but your code that relies on this behavior but is being run in a different environment will not behave the same, and there is no obvious indication that this will have happened. If you use this option, *use it in every script* (that uses `$` indexing). Or use `[[`.

Comment: ok but `warnPartialMatchDollar` is only to produce warning, not actually turn this behaviour off, right? That's what I'm looking for.

Comment: True, it doesn't *change* the behavior (you cannot do that), it only tells you when it's doing it behind your back. Actually, in that perspective, it might be beneficial to have this enabled during development (though during "production" use it might not be seen, depending on your use). (Because `$` and the other Extract operators are all `.Primitive` functions, you are unlikely to be able to change their default behavior ... without recompiling R. And for that, good luck.)

Comment: Unfortunately, the only way you can *"turn off this behaviour"* is to use `[[` instead to target its default of `exact=TRUE`. (You can't even do `\`$\`(mtcars,"cy",exact=TRUE)`, truly up-a-creek.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `[` or `[[` instead.

`a["cov"]` will return a list with a NULL element.
`a[["cov"]]` will return the NULL element directly.

Comment: thank you Steven! That's a good solution. Anyway do you know why is this and if this can be turned off? I was used to `$cov` because it's much shorter

Comment: You can see the documentation with `?\`$\``. You'll see that `[[` has an `exact` parameter defaulted to `TRUE`. `$` works like `[[..., exact = FALSE`.